# Can't display Images that are uploaded to firebase Store in the right order

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I have a gallery, where I display images by getting their URL from the firebase storage. In the storage they are named (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc.) and I want to sort them by their names. But instead every time I reload the page, I get different order. May somebody can help me with this issue?

The itemRef.sortBy('name').getDownloadURL() didn't work
What else can I try to add to my code to resolve this problem?

```
created() {
    let storageRef = storage.ref();
    let listRef = storageRef.child('photos_main/');
    listRef.listAll().then(result => {
      result.items.forEach(itemRef => {
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          this.items.push(url)
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message)
        })
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the order, I think [Promise.all()](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/) is going to be helpful.

Here is how I'd do it:

```js
async created () {
   const imageNames = await this.getImageNames();
   const imageUrls = await Promise.all(
       imageNames.map(imageName => this.getDownloadURL(imageName))
   );

   console.log(imageUrls)
}
```

`imageNames.map(imageName => this.getDownloadURL(imageName))` will create an array of promises.
The promises will all **start at the same time**, but will get resolved in the order that they appear.